# Cannot post to DRF modelviewset - request.data immediately emptied

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I've done what feels like the *absolute minimum* in setting up a rest endpoint in front of a django model, but I cannot post to it from the browseable API.

On `djangorestframework==3.3.0`, all posts to `/api/transactions/` are rejected.

**models.py**

```
class TransactionQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    ...

class Transaction(models.Model):
    objects = TransactionQuerySet.as_manager()

    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True,
                          editable=False,
                          default=uuid4,
                          unique=True)

    description = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(default=get_timestamp,
                                     editable=False)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '{0} ({1})'.format(self.description,
                                  to_decimal(self.amount))

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-timestamp']
```

**serializers.py**

```
class TransactionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Transaction
        exclude = ()
```

**views.py**

```
class TransactionViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Transaction.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TransactionSerializer
```

**tracking.urls**

```
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter
from django.conf.urls import url

import views

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'transactions', views.TransactionViewSet)
urlpatterns = router.urls
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^api/api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
    url(r'^api/', include('tracking.urls')),
]
```

Submitting the form gets this response

```
HTTP 400 Bad Request
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept
Allow: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS

{
    "amount": [
        "This field is required."
    ],
    "description": [
        "This field is required."
    ]
}
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can post to the endpoint with authentication disabled.  Apparently, it is related to [this bug](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/issues/3588) in DRF