# Retrieving empty data from request.data when using modelviewset

Tags: django, api, rest, frameworks

I'm using DRF ModelViewSet and trying to add new endpoint to upload some file via post.

My view:

```
class TreeViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated, TokenHasReadWriteScope]
    lookup_field = 'id'
    queryset = Tree.nodes

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        return partial(TreeSerializer, user=self.request.user.userprofile.id)

    def get_object(self):
        qset = copy.deepcopy(self.get_queryset())
        try:
            return qset.get(id=self.kwargs[self.lookup_field])
        except:
            raise Http404("No Person matches the given query.")

    @detail_route(
        methods=['post'],
        url_path='gedcom')
    def upload_gedcom(self, request, id=None):
        print request.data
```

The endpoint is:

> ..../tree/{pk}/gedcom/ (upload_gedcom)

- **PROBLEM: *print request.data*** returns empty QueryDict.
- I already tried this solution:
  [Django Rest Framework: empty request.data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30671808/django-rest-framework-empty-request-data) and did not work for me.
- For testing i'm using postman:
  [here is the Postman screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSfU5.png)
- before implementing this endpoint, I had other enpoint in other view that solved the method (upload_gedcom), but i used a list_router instead of detailed one. This way works, but is conceptually wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the issue can be related with this: [Cannot post to DRF modelviewset - request.data immediately emptied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33556398/cannot-post-to-drf-modelviewset-request-data-immediately-emptied) that takes you to this DRF bug: [HTML form in generics.listCreateAPI is not taking values #3574](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/issues/3574)
. I'm not sure about this, if someone can give me some feedback I will be really grateful.
I hope this can help somebody.

Comment: **SOLVED**:
The problem was I used the "'oauth2_provider.backends.OAuth2Backend'" for AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS
_settings.py_ 
`AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'oauth2_provider.backends.OAuth2Backend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)`